# In Sphinx documentation, is it possible to use the module name to specify a code sample to be included?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'd like to include a code example in my sphinx documentation.
I don't, however, want to refer to the file by its path,
but would rather specify it by its module name.

That is, instead of doing it the way indicated here [Showing code examples](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/markup/code.html)

```
.. literalinclude example.py
```

or

```
.. literalinclude ../../example.py
```

I'd rather do (for example)

```
.. includemodule mymodule.example
```

Is this possible to do without writing a custom extension?
Or, what is the simplest way to write such an extension?

Comment: The documentation is very clear: "filename" not "module".

Comment: I was wondering if there was an alternative that I didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

You can reference other classes by using something like this:

```
:class:`~module.submodule.Class`
```

If you add the examples as doctest to the class than you have examples which are guaranteed to work since they are directly runnable.

Comment: How does this help my problem?

Comment: @Ed L: You could link to the specific module and put the example in there. It will both work as documentation and as test if you use doctests.